# C - How to assign value to char**

Tags: c

How to assign value to char** in C.

```
char** departmentList;

departmentList[0] = "hahaha";
```

above code is running in a function but failed all other places. Im using gcc 10.2.0 as the compiler.

Comment: The code you've written does not assign a value to a `char **`.  It is attempting to assign a value to a `char *` and failing because it is dereferencing an uninitialized `char **`  If it is "running in a function" that is because undefined behavior sometimes appears to "work".

Comment: All pointers must point at valid memory before they are used. `departmentList` is not, so you cannot de-reference it with `[0]`. Why are you using `char**` if the intention is to point at a single string?

Comment: @Lundin I want to make an array of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must allocate some buffer to `departmentList` before dereferencing that.

```
char** departmentList;

departmentList = malloc(sizeof(*departmentList)); // allocate

departmentList[0] = "hahaha";
```

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` (if it is not present) to use `malloc()`.

Comment: Right,but it is nice to add that this would work for single department only...